# CommonJS better than Namespacing in Titanium Apps?

Tags: javascript, design-patterns, titanium, commonjs

Appcelerator recommend the use of CommonJS-modules in Titanium Apps: https://wiki.appcelerator.org/display/guides/Mobile+Best+Practices

However, on their docs, I cannot find a reasonable answer to my reasonable question: **Why?**

What does CommonJS do that good Namespacing doesn't? As far as I can see, it's simply a way of including modules!

**Edit:** 
Specifically, what benefits do I get from using CommonJS in the context of Titanium?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[CommonJS modules](http://wiki.commonjs.org/wiki/Modules/1.1) do more than just namespacing. It also helps you organize your code and define your modules dependencies (using [define](https://github.com/amdjs/amdjs-api/wiki/AMD) or require), both of which is not enforced in normal namespacing.

Of course you can do all of that yourself somehow, but last but not least, CommonJS has become a de factor standard and it is usually better to rely on standards than rolling your own package, dependency and namespacing framework or guidelines.

Comment: Also: 1. Keeps the global namespace clean. 2. You can easily override real modules with mock modules for unit testing. 3. Less verbose than long namespace strings. 4. Namespaces are sooo nineties.

Comment: Thanks guys, that's really helpful, however I really need to know more about why CommonJS is such a good idea in the context of Titanium!?

Comment: It doesn't matter what platform. CommonJS modules are a good idea in *any* ECMAScript based application.

Comment: True but I hoped to get a more Titanium-specific answer.

Comment: Well the Titanium specific answer is: Because they recommend using it. See the above answer for why. These are exactly the benefits when using it with Titanium as well. I'm not sure what else you are looking for.

Comment: Is there any difference in memory usage of an app when using commonjs instead of namespacing?

Comment: I doubt it. It's one additional function call per module during load time. You probably won't even be able to measure it. And if you're initializing thousands of modules during load time something else is wrong with the application.